# How to stop external library from polluting app output with its messages?

Tags: java, jar, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I've written a console app in Java, that uses Google Protocol Buffers for serialization.
However, when that code is used, during library loading, it outputs some warnings about illegal reflective access operations.

AFAIK, that's some minor Google annoyance that doesn't really affect anything, so I would like my app not to dump that trash to output.
At the same time, I obviously want my app to output its own stuff as normal.

How does one generally go about things like this?
What would be a good way to handle this concrete situation?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to add a logger and not use the standard console output. You can read about slf4j. It has many advantages over the standard output. You can have different levels of the log you want to see - info,debug,warn,error etc. So you can limit the amount of information you read. Also you will keep previous outputs in files and also you can configure different appenders - so different classes write their outputs into different files.

Basically this is the preferred way for most java applications and there is a reason why

Comment: So that all output must go through a logging library and nothing I don't want seeps through. Yes, sounds viable.